# Laravel pagination without refreshing page

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination

I found this Ajax for pagination without refreshing the page. 
Pagination works, but page is refreshing every time, it's annoying because table is on bottom of the page.

Can you check, maybe I made some mistake. Or give me some ideas to fix this.

**Controller:**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $satwork = DB::table('companies')
                ->leftJoin('devices', 'companies.id', '=', 'devices.companyId')
                ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'devices.id', '=', 'vehicles.deviceId')
                ->leftJoin('drivers', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'drivers.vehicleId')
                ->select('companies.company_name', 'devices.device_type', 'vehicles.license_plate', 'drivers.driver_name')
                ->paginate(5);

                return view('/welcome', compact('satwork'));

}

public function fetch_data(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) 
    {
        $satwork = DB::table('companies')
                ->leftJoin('devices', 'companies.id', '=', 'devices.companyId')
                ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'devices.id', '=', 'vehicles.deviceId')
                ->leftJoin('drivers', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'drivers.vehicleId')
                ->select('companies.company_name', 'devices.device_type', 'vehicles.license_plate', 'drivers.driver_name')
                ->paginate(5);

        return view('pagination', compact('satwork'))->render();
    }
}
```

**welcome.blade**

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="table_data">
            @include('pagination')
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- pagination -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
            fetch_data(page);
        });

        function fetch_data(page) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "//pagination?page=" + page,
                success: function(satwork) {
                    $('#table_data').html(satwork);
                }
            });
        }

    });
    }
</script>
```

**pagination blade**

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($satwork as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row -> company_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row -> device_type}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row -> license_plate}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row -> driver_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    {!! $satwork->links() !!}
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('/welcome/pagination', 'WelcomeController@fetch_data');
```

Comment: Does page get refreshed on pagination click ??

Comment: Yes, and thats is the problem.

Comment: Check the console for Js error and make sure the class `.pagination` exists with the pagination DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request URL to fetch the pagination is not correct.

```
url: "//pagination?page=" + page
```

That should be `url: "/welcome/pagination?page=" + page`

```
function fetch_data(page) {

    var l = window.location;

    // the request path should be 
    // domain.com/welcome/pagination

    $.ajax({
        url: l.origin + l.pathname + "?page=" + page,
        success: function(satwork) {
            $('#table_data').html(satwork);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with dataTables

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#companies').DataTable({
         "lengthMenu": [[2, 3, 5, 10, 20, -1], [2, 3, 5, 10, 20, "All"]]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

And it's working.